# Why does this code keep running else? python3

Tags: python, if-statement

```
check = input("check for x or y. ")

while True:
    print("input was" , check)
    if input == "x":
        print("Following x")
        break
    elif input == "y":
        print("Following y")
        break
    else:
        print("Following else")
        break

print("end")
```

I am trying to run the if statement depending on the input but regardless of input it always goes to else.

Comment: (Side note, there's no need for a `while` loop when you always break out of it on the first iteration.)

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing the `input` function, not the result (`check`) of calling the `input` function and reading the input from the keyboard

```
check = input("check for x or y. ")

while True:
    print("input was" , check)
    if check == "x":
        print("Following x")
        break
    elif check == "y":
        print("Following y")
        break
    else:
        print("Following else")
        break

print("end")
```